# what will happen in Python multiple Inheritance problem?

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have written two classes "A" and "B", where in both classes you have added method with same name called "print". Then I have written another class "C" which extends both "A" and "B" like this: "class C(A,B):", If I  call "print" from the instance of class "C", then what will happen

Comment: What prevents you from testing this yourself?

Answer (score 1):

It's a complex subject... and things are different depending on which python version and how the classes are declared.

In Python3 there is an easy solution however... for example:

```
class A:
    pass
class B:
    pass

class C(A, B):
    pass

print(C.__mro__)
```

will show `(__main__.C, __main__.A, __main__.B, object)` meaning that the class `C` will be searched first, followed by `A`, then by `B` and finally by `object` when looking up a method.

Note that there are cases in which Python will not allow the creation of a confusing class hierarchy... consider:

```
class A: pass                                                                                                                        
class B: pass                                                                                                                        
class C(A, B): pass                                                                                                                  
class D(B, A): pass
```

What should happen if we create a new class `E` inheriting from both `C` and `D`? Should `A` be searched before `B` or after `B`?
Python solution is simple:

```
class E(C, D): pass                                                                                                                  

----> 1 class E(C, D): pass
TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases A, B
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    class C(A, B):
TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases A, B
I am getting this error
why? can you tell me plz

Comment: @unbolt: see edited answer for a case in which this error is generated. For your case there is a similar problem, the class dependency graph is intricate and you didn't follow a strict order when declaring multiple bases so Python cannot find a reasonable consistent way to handle inheritance.